# AngularJS Posting with dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, html, .net, angularjs

I'm a bit new to AngularJS, and I need a bit of help posting data. I am creating a new input box on keypress of each input box. Well when my user clicks the add button I want to post data to the db via angularjs. My first input box successfully posts the data to the db, but the following input boxes do nothing on ng-click.

**Here's my HTML:**

```
 <div id="divAddRow" class="row" ng-app="GroupApp"> 
    <div class="col-lg-8" ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
          <div id="row1" class="input-group input-group-lg addGroup w3-animate-bottom">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg txtAddGroup" ng-model="group.GroupName" placeholder="Group Name..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button id="btn" type="button" ng-click="AddGroup();"
                          class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </span>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Here's where I create the controls dynamically using clone() of the first div:**

```
$(document).on('keydown', '.txtAddGroup', (function (e) {
            //this function clones the parent group and if one below it does not exist, it adds it to the DOM
            var currentRowNum = $(this).parent().attr('id').replace(/row/, '');
            var nxtRowNum = parseInt(currentRowNum, 10) + 1;
            if ($('#row' + nxtRowNum).parent().length === 0) {
                $('div.addGroup:last').after($('<br/>').add($('div.addGroup:first').clone().prop('id', 'row' + nxtRowNum)));                   
                $('div.addGroup:last input').val('');
            }
        }));
```

**Here is my angularjs script:**

```
var app = angular
       .module('GroupApp', [])
       .controller('GroupCtrl', function ($scope, AddGroup) {
           $scope.AddGroup = function()
           {
               AddGroup.AddGrouptoDB($scope.group);
           }

       }) .factory("AddGroup", ['$http', function ($http){
var fac = {};
fac.AddGrouptoDB = function(group)
{
    $http.post("/Group/AddGroup", group).success(function (response) {
        alert(response.status);
    })


}
return fac;
}])
```

How do I accomplish this? Let me know if I am not being clear enough. Thank you for any help!!

Comment: Mixing jQuery DOM manipulation in this manner with Angular is a path down a very dark road leading to madness. OK, maybe it's not that bad, but there are Angular ways to do what you're doing (using `ng-repeat` and adding items to a collection that you maintain and manage in the controller) that will make your life far, far easier in both the short- and long-term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe we can do this in a more angular way...

`clone` would not be my first choice to do this. I would use `ng-repeat` instead where `ng-click` extends a value on you model. This way you can assign a separate attribute to each of your inputs.

It would look something like this:

html:

```
<div id="divAddRow" class="row" ng-app="GroupApp"> 
    <div class="col-lg-8" ng-controller="GroupCtrl">
          <div id="row1" ng-repeat="group in groups" class="input-group input-group-lg addGroup w3-animate-bottom">
                    <input class="form-control input-lg txtAddGroup" ng-model="group.name" placeholder="Group Name..." />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                      <button id="btn" type="button" ng-click="AddGroup(group);"
                          class="btn btn-success btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                    </span>
           </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular
       .module('GroupApp', [])
       .controller('GroupCtrl', function ($scope, AddGroup) {
           var id_generator = function(id){
               return id + 1 // or query for the last id or generate a guid
           }
           $scope.groups = [{'id': 1, 'name': ''}];
           $scope.AddGroup = function(group)
           {
               AddGroup.AddGrouptoDB(group);
               var newgroup = {'id':id_generator($scope.groups[$scope.groups.length - 1].id),
                               'name': ''}
               $scope.groups.push(newgroup);

           }

       }) .factory("AddGroup", ['$http', function ($http){
var fac = {};
fac.AddGrouptoDB = function(group)
{
    $http.post("/Group/AddGroup", group).success(function (response) {
        alert(response.status);
    })


}
return fac;
}]);
```

Comment: I see where you are going here, but how can I make each group unique for when it is added? track by?

Comment: Normally, your backend would keep track of the groups in the api, and you initialize your angular model with an `http.get()`, a sub-optimal way is to generate guids in your client. I will edit my response so you can see how this would be.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The only thing that was causing issues was how you were getting the last item in the array. I edited the answer. Thanks again mate!

Answer (score 2):

Actually when you use angular you should forget about what you've learned in jquery.
Back to your jquery code, what happens over there is out of the angular digest loop. Being more simple, angular doesn't see the jquery logic.
You can try using $scope.$apply() at the end of the keydown event callback (I don't really recommend it).

A better solution is to use angular events directives.
See this link: [from the angular js docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeydown)

Answer (score 2):

When your page loads, angular app is bootstrapped. And during this time, it attached all the watchers on models, sets up the directive (`ngClick` in your case) and so on. So, by the time page is loaded completely, angular is done attaching certain behaviour to DOM element (via directive). This won't happen for the DOM elements, which you are adding dynamically. And thus directives on those dynamically created elements are useless. Angular is not at all aware of those directives. And so, they are not responding to click events.

You can read documentation about directives

https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

First few paragraphs will be helpful for you.

And to solve this issue, $compile is what you are looking for.